# Executing a code at a desired fixed time in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Ive been developing a signal generator in pine to work on indexes. I am stuck at a part wherein i wish to execute exit code at close of 3 PM/ 1500 hrs 5 min candle everyday. however I have not been able to read the current time and execute the code.
This is what i have tried
timecheck = hour ==1500
I'll request for support on the issue please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Time, Dates, and Sessions** section of the PineCoders FAQ at https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#time-dates-and-sessions helped me do something like this.

If you create a new Indicator in PineScript with this content it might give you something useful to start from:

```
//@version=4
study("Time Example", overlay=false)

// You can plot your value only at a certain time.
// Here we plot 9 if it is the right time, and 0 if not.
// Replace 9 with a call to whatever function you want.

plot(not na(time("5", "1500-1504")) ? 9 : 0, color=color.blue)

// Or, you can set a value to na at first:
var int red_val = na

// And then change it only when the right time comes,
// when you are finally able to calculate it.
// Here we check if this bar's start time, if converted
// to 5-minute resolution, would start at 1500.
// Note: this uses the time zone of the exchange that
// the current symbol is traded on, not your local time.

if not na(time("5", "1500-1504"))
    // You would put own your calculation here.
    // This dayofmonth() call is just an example.
    red_val := dayofmonth(timenow)

// Then, for example, you can plot the final result
// of your calculation later on in your code:
plot(red_val, color=color.red)
```

In either example, the `not na(time("5", "1500-1504"))` is the important bit for your situation. There are other (possibly better) ways of doing it, if you check the FAQ linked above.

The PineScript reference at https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_time is also useful but it's really the examples in the FAQ that helped me the most.

Comment: thanks a ton man...it helped me sort out the issue immediately